# Is that possible to get client's windows login name from web app in intranet?

Tags: asp.net, windows, login-name

I was wondering is that possible to get the client's windows login name when it accesses a website in intranet? I googled a lot of methods, but what i can get is the server's windows login name?

Is that possible to get client's windows login name from web app in intranet?

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean, are you in a Network with Active Directory Domain?

Comment: Not sure, need to check with System Team. If so, is there any solutions?

Comment: How do your users authenticate with your intranet? Forms Authentication or Windows Authentication?